# How to check the value of input

Tags: javascript, html

Its app / site like brain trainer

```
  <body style="text-align: center;">
    <h3 id="num1"></h3>

    <h3 id="num2"></h3>
    <input type="text" id="ans" />
    <button id="myBtn" onclick="clickFunction()">Button</button>
    <p id="ind"></p>
    <script>
        var i = 0;
        var number1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
        var number2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
        var result = number1 * number2;
        document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML = number1;
        document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = number2;
        let answer = document.getElementById("ans");
        if (result == answer) {
          document.getElementById("ind").innerHTML =
            "Indicator : Right " + i++ + "times.";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("ind").innerHTML =
            "Indicator : Right " + i-- + " times.";
        }
  answer.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
    </script>
```

I need to add a button which should submit the text in input

And i want to check if it met the condition, if it does, the counter should be increasing

Comment: so you want someone to write the `clickFunction` for you? What is it supposed to do exactly?

Comment: yeah, but I cant

Comment: "Please help" isn't an answerable question.  You need to describe the specific problem you're having in your code, such as a specific operation which is producing an error or unexpected result.  If you're just asking how to create a function in JavaScript, or how to write JavaScript code at all, then the Google search you're looking for is "javascript tutorials".

Comment: it supposed to check the value of input, if it right the counter increses

Comment: Please learn [ask], this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your input entries have ID's, you can select the input entry in JavaScript and get the value in the box using
`document.getElementById(id).value` then simply code the logic to check if the answer is correct based on this value.

If you want to have buttons do something, firstly your button needs to have an onclick attribute like so:
`<button onclick='myFunction();'></button>`
then in JavaScript the function looks like this:

```
function myFunction(){

}
```

Everything inside the { } brackets will be executed AFTER pressing the button. This is where you will need to get your .value and compare with your answer.